# -[__NSDictionaryI arrayForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I got this error when using the AFNetworking 3.0 library.  Code:

```
[manager GET:@"..."
      parameters:nil
        progress:nil
         success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
             NSArray *result = [responseObject arrayForKey:@"items"];

             self.objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseObject];
             [self.tableView reloadData];
         } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); }];
```

When I use arrayWithArray, I get:

```
[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:]: array argument is not an NSArray'
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  I only see your code here.

Comment: The error message clearly states that `responseObject` is a dictionary which does not respond to `arrayForKey`. A quick look in the documentation reveals that there are two classes which respond to `arrayForKey`: `NSUserDefaults` and `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`

Comment: +1 @vadian: `reponseObject` is a `NSDictionary` object. Admitting, that it has a value for key `@"items"` and that the value is a `NSArray` object, you should at least do `self.objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: result];` and not `self.objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseObject];`...

Comment: @Larme I know I should, but I'm already breaking at the arrayForKey line, so that wouldn't exactly do much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should never trust user input, data that comes from network and other 3rd-party data with dubious origin, so you should always check if you are getting what you expect. Even if you assume that `responseObject` is a `NSDictionary`, you must check it in order to be sure and correctly handle possible errors.
2. In your example (according to the crash message) `responseObject` is of `NSDictionary` type. This class does not have `-[arrayForKey:]` method. When you are trying to call a method (*to send a message, actually*) that is not implemented in the hierarchy, you get that type of exception – "unrecognized selector sent to instance". Also, [check this article](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1571955-forwardinvocation) regarding forwarding for extended info.

Fixed snippet:

```
[manager GET:@"..."
 parameters:nil
  progress:nil
   success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary*)responseObject;
        id items = dic[@"items"];
        if ([items isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            self.objects = [(NSArray*)items mutableCopy];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: \"items\" is not an array");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: unexpected type of the response object");
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {             
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: +1, because you helped.  BTW, my data is always definite.. It's my own PHP file and it always comes out in JSON form.  Thanks for the solution with [].